# Crawler returning crawled results with \n's, how to get rid of these

Tags: python, json, scrapy

The intention of this crawler is to return all the texts on a page along with the links, and we're trying to store the scraped data in json files, but the json files are coming with outputs containing redundancies such as the \n 's

Here is the scrapy spider:

```
import itemloaders
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
#from crawl.items import SpideyItem



class crawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spidey'
    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1,
        'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 1,
    }

    def parse_item(self, response):

        item = dict()
        item['url'] = response.url.strip()
        item['title'] = response.meta['link_text'].strip()
        # extracting basic body
        item['body'] = '\n'.join(response.xpath(
            '//text()').extract())
        # or better just save whole source
        #item['source'] = response.body

        yield item
```

Example output in a json file:

```
{"url": "https://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/miracles/page/1/", "title": "miracles", "body": "\n\n\n\t\n\n\t\nQuotes to Scrape\n\n    \n\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n    \n\n        \n\n            \n\n                \n\n                    \nQuotes to Scrape\n\n                \n\n            \n\n            \n\n                \n\n                \n                    \nLogin\n\n                \n                \n\n            \n\n        \n\n    \n\n\nViewing tag: \nmiracles\n\n\n\n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n        \n\u201cThere are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.\u201d\n\n        \nby \nAlbert Einstein\n\n        \n(about)\n\n        \n\n        \n\n            Tags:\n            \n \n            \n            \ninspirational\n\n            \n            \nlife\n\n            \n            \nlive\n\n            \n            \nmiracle\n\n            \n            \nmiracles\n\n            \n        \n\n    \n\n\n    \n\n        \n\n            \n            \n        \n\n    \n\n    \n\n    \n\n        \n            \nTop Ten tags\n\n            \n            \n\n            \nlove\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \ninspirational\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \nlife\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \nhumor\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \nbooks\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \nreading\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \nfriendship\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \nfriends\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \ntruth\n\n            \n\n            \n            \n\n            \nsimile\n\n            \n\n            \n        \n    \n\n\n\n\n    \n\n    \n\n        \n\n            \n\n                Quotes by: \nGoodReads.com\n\n            \n\n            \n\n                Made with \n\u2764\n by \nScrapinghub\n\n            \n\n        \n\n    \n\n\n\n"},
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer to your question, exactly as written, is to use `replace`:

```
>>> "A lot of newline\n\n\n    characters\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n".replace("\n", "")
'A lot of newline    characters'
```

Cleaning scraped contents is often a bit more involved, though. You typically don't want to unconditionally remove all newline characters, and another thing may be the presence of excessive whitespace (such as in your example).
For those situations you may want to use regex instead. A very simple example is:

```
>>> s = "A lot of newline\n\n\n  \t\t  characters\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
>>> re.sub("(\s)+", r"\1", s)
'A lot of newline characters\n'
```

The above expression is trivial, but regular expressions can be made very complicated to encode a lot of rules that can replace many lines of code when cleaning, searching or verifying textual data etc.

Comment: sorry, but i am a bit lost, can you please clarify what change do I exactly need to make where so that it cleans all the json files? because I am also having trouble loading these to elasticsearch because of this reason.

Comment: Since you want to clean up `item["body"]`, which is a string, you can do `re.sub("(\s)+", r"\1", item["body"])`. Note that it doesn't substitute in-place, so you'll need to (re-)assign the return value. Btw, you probably want to use `return` over `yield` in your example - your function only ever returns one item.